# Has there been a change to window.print() in Edge?

Tags: javascript, html, printing

I have noticed, of late, that window.print() seems to be acting differently in
Edge as opposed to Firefox. Namely, if window.print() is immediately followed by, for instance, window.location.href="/index.php", then no printing occurs. I've tried a few alternatives such as window.location.assign("/index.php") or even history.go(-1).

No print dialog appears, and no printing happens. The redirection does happen. The only way I've been able to get printing is to remove the redirection entirely, and do any navigation manually. Not an ideal solution.

Any ideas would be welcome.

Comment: Maybe add a timeout to the redirection so the browser does not skip the print

Comment: Redirect in an [afterprint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/afterprint_event) handler.

Comment: onafterprint() worked. Thank you Teemu.